# How do I get rmi registry to work on windows command prompt?

Tags: java, windows, rmi

So I need to work with some distributed systems on java RMI. I have already set a environment variable path to my JDK bin and so I can use javac and java commands on the command line.
However, when I try to set the rmi registry using rmiregistry, it doesn't work. It doesn't return "rmiregistry is not a recognised internal or external command" but it runs but it stays running for ages and I have to press ctrl+C to stop it from running as it won't stop itself.

The code I am entering into the command line is:

```
rmiregistry 8888 &
```

I've tried that on Linux before and it seems to work how I want it to but it's not working on Windows. What can I do to get RMI working on the windows command line?

Answer (score 0):

The trailing `&` in a linux shell runs a program without waiting for it to terminate.
 
The windows equivalent is

```
start /B rmiregistry 8888
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type the command below to start your rmiregistry. When it gets started, the rmiregistry.exe window will pop up on your screen.

```
start rmiregistry
```